# Extracting the links from a website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a dataframe df which has two columns (PMID, DOI), I want to pass each PMID into a website as input value and get the DOI href link as output and store it in the second column (DOI), an example is shown below,

```
PMID     | DOI
20022636   10.1016/j.molimm.2009.11.027
20023032   10.1128/JB.01375-09  
2002360
2002352




 driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.pmid2cite.com/pmid-to-doi-converter")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Consent']"))).click()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(str(row['PMID']))
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#formInput"))).send_keys(row['PMID'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/form/button").click()
    #print(driver.page_source)
    #print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/p[1]/span[2]/a"))).get_attribute('href'))
    #print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/p[1]/span[2]/a")))])
    res = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/p[1]/span[2]/a")))]
    df.iloc[index, 1] = res[0]
    
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` error because when webpages loaded a `consent form` appear. you need to **accept** the `consent form` then it will be able to interact the other elements.

Use WebDriverWait() and wait for consent form first to click and then the input element.

```
driver.get("https://www.pmid2cite.com/pmid-to-doi-converter")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Consent']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#formInput"))).send_keys("20022636")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

browser snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, it returns DOI for every PMID's in a given dataframe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.pmid2cite.com/pmid-to-doi-converter")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Consent']"))).click()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        
        #print(str(row['PMID']))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#formInput"))).send_keys(row['PMID'])
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/form/button").click()
        res = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/p[1]/span[2]/a")))]
        print(res)
        df.iloc[index, 1] = res[0]
    
    except TimeoutException:
        
        df.iloc[index, 1] = 'NA'
        
        
print('Done')

    PMID        DOI
0   277290620   10.1186/s13075-016-1133-8
1   110534327   10.1074/jbc.M004690200
2   97257504    NA
3   78270291    NA
```